# asp.net core date field not posting back to controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, date, razor-pages

I am using asp.net core with a razor page and the view model has a field, SearchDate, that is date only.  The date field only posts back to the MVC controller when the parameter is a string ->

*public async Task LoadOrders(string searchDate)*.

I would like to send the entire view model that is associated with the razor page to the MVC controller because there are other view model attributes that I need.  If I changed the signature of the method above to:

*public async Task EOMOrdersLoad(SomeViewModel model)*

The date in the view model is always null.  The field on the cshtml is defined as below

asp-for="SearchDate" type="date" class="form-control" name="SearchDate" id="SearchDate" style="width: 40%" value=""

I have removed the 'value=""' attribute and it does not affect what is sent back to the MVC controller. I have also tried using @Html.EditorFor and that does not work either.

I am hoping it is something stupid I am doing that is fixable rather than an issue with how MVC posts back date field from the view.

I have looked through stackoverflow and can not really find anything that matches my issues but have tried a lot of different suggested solutions.

Comment: Please provide the part of your code with the issue

Comment: I think you need to learn first some basics asp.net core tutorials.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following example below.

View model:

```cs
public class SomeViewModel
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime SearchDate { get; set; }    
}
```

The controller methods:

```cs
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new SomeViewModel()
    {
        Description = "description 123",
        SearchDate = DateTime.Now
    };
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult EOMOrdersLoad(SomeViewModel data)
{
    //... your code here
    return RedirectToAction("Index", data);
}
```

And the `Index.cshtml` view:

```
@model Models.SomeViewModel

<form id="form" asp-action="EOMOrdersLoad">
    <div >
        <label asp-for="Description" class="form-label">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </label>
        <textarea asp-for="Description" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" ></textarea>
        <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="invalid-feedback"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label asp-for="SearchDate" class="form-label">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SearchDate)
        </label>
        <input asp-for="SearchDate" type="date" class="form-control" >
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Jackdaw - tried your code and the issue still exists which is - the [HttpPost] not reflecting a changed value from the screen in the model.  What is being returned is the initial value from the "Index" method.  Oddly enough, the "Description" is in the model but for some reason the date is not.

Comment: @ChrisW: Strange, because this works for me. 1) Can you add your controller and view  code to the post, please? 2) Try to disable the layout by adding  `@{ Layout = null; }` to the view. Just for testing purpose. Sometimes scripts ans css styles loaded with it can cause this problem.

Comment: found the issue and I think it is a stupid one on my part.  The view model definition for the SearchDate was DateOnly.  The view was input type=date and I don't think that when it was posted to the MVC controller, it knew how to correlate an input="date" to a DateOnly view model field.  Once I changed the view model field to DateTime, your code works.  Thanks for all your help!